Will using ADSL filters with full-fibre broadband create any issues?
My home broadband is currently a fibre to cabinet system and rather than using plug-in ADSL filters I chose to replace the standard phone face plates with ones that have integral filters. My telephones are currently connected to the incoming copper cable to which is also connected my broadband router.
My current broadband contract will shortly be coming to an end and I am considering changing to a full-fibre system whilst retaining my existing landline number and telephone handsets.
I am advised that with a full-fibre system there is no need to use ADSL filtering but before I commit to changing over to a full-fibre system I would appreciate your advice as to whether by retaining the ADSL filtered faceplates this will create any problems with my phone usage or router or  would I need to the change the faceplates over for ones without integral ADSL filters?

Aside - there is a chance your fibre connection will be provisioned with an ONT on the end with an ATA built into it.  This would render your copper pairs obsolete because your voice circuit would be delivered over the fibre too.   Comment because not-an-answer.   Talk to your ISP.

Doesn't your fiber provider offer VOIP? In that case you wouldn't need any filter.

ADSL filters are just low-pass filters that are intended to stop the high frequency DSL/internet signals from leaking through to the telephone. Typically these are entirely passive filters, though you may get higher quality active filters.
There is no need to remove the filters if you stop using ADSL for internet. The phone will still work exactly as it did before. The filter basically just becomes redundant.
If it were a bulky inline plug, people would be free to remove them for aesthetic reasons. But for integrated ones, that isn't really a consideration.

One reason for removing the DSL filter/splitter on the analogue line is if it breaks down and interferes with audio quality.   Though this assumes the copper pair is still used for pots delivery.

It depends how your provider is delivering phone service after your full fibre is installed.

If you are retaining the copper line for voice, the high frequency DSL signal may be removed.  You can either keep or remove the filters, it makes little difference.  It's possible they don't actually disconnect or turn off the DSL equipment from the wires (just cancel your login), in which case you'd need to keep the filter.
If your provider is instead offering a voice-over-IP service (eg in the UK it's branded 'digital voice'), the phone is generated locally - either in the router, or an additional box.  This has a phone socket which you have to plug your analogue phone into, and the wall phone socket will be out of service.  There's no point transferring the DSL filter to the socket on the back of the router, although having it won't cause any bad effects.
Your provider may offer an alterative DECT, ethernet or wifi phone for voice.  Here everything is fully digital and there's no analogue phone socket you can plug the filter into.

